# How can I add a custom fee in woocommerce that is calculated after tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I've added a custom fee to my checkout page with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + $woocommerce->cart->tax_total ) * $percentage;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'My Fee', $surcharge, false, '' );

}
```

Everything works as expected except adding in the tax.  I thought adding

```
$woocommerce->cart->tax_total
```

would do the trick, but that value is returning 0.

Is there some way to calculate tax before this fee is calculated?

Comment: Did you remove the default `add_action`? Also the first argument of `add_fee` takes a string. See: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee

Comment: @Musk  Sorry, that code is a bit messed up.  I had used that arg to print out what the tax total was.  Normally it would be a string like 'Special Fee' or something.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this one, but here maybe this class documentation could help you find your answers. `https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#737-763`

Comment: Have tested this against WooCommerce 2.4.7 and is working as  expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the *correct* way to handle this issue.

But, I've got a working solution to my problem.

I just calculated the tax and added it to the fee calculation.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->taxes);
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + $taxes ) * $percentage;   
    // Make sure that you return false here.  We can't double tax people!
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, false, '' );

}
```

I got the following line from the [Woocommerce documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1176-1371).  Taking care to set the taxable variable to false so as to not double tax people.

```
$taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->taxes);
```

Comment: That's not calculating the taxes for you correctly. This will give you taxes for the subtotal of the cart and will not take shipping taxes (or any other taxes) into account.

Comment: @adamj I'm not sure what you mean.  My goal was to calculate tax based on the subtotal of the cart then add that amount plus shipping fees and the custom surcharge to the total.  It sounds like you're suggesting I tax everything, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Your goal was to get the `tax_total`, as stated in the question. The method above doesn't give you the tax total, it just gives you the tax for the subtotal. Unless this is what you wanted, I'd recommend changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to grab the total taxes:

```
$total_taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->get_taxes());
```